Buick verano transmisión
I had the transmission recently replaced on my Buick verano 2016 they said if I had  any problems with it it has guaranteed no they say I need to replace the speed sensor doesn't the speed sensor part of the transmission or be replaced if changing the transmission wouldn't the be part of the guaranteed because now is changing me 1000

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd go get a second opinion. The speed sensor in the transmission costs under $25 from what I'm looking at. That's charging you $975 in labor and shop costs. And remember, if you went to the dealership for this, I'd stay away in the future. We affectionately (tongue-in-cheek) call them the "stealer-ship", if you get my drift.

Yea he says it's because it's hard to get to it takes 41/5 hrs but he did my transmission he said it had. Guaranteed I searched it it's actually p0716its called the transmission speed sensor shouldn't he had changed that when he changed the transmission or it should fit for the guaranteed that he mentioned about the transmission having guaranteed I'm asking so I could confront him about it. I'm a girl so  they know I don't know alot

It makes no difference to me that you're a girl ... we try to practice the no pink tax rule here. That said, unless you specified there was an issue with the speed sensor, it isn't something which would be replaced during the transmission overhaul. I'll stand by my suggestion of getting a 2nd opinion.

Thank you I appreciate it

Unless there was an issue with the speed sensor when the transmission was rebuilt (or replaced), there'd be no reason for them to change it. A new one would not come on a new or rebuilt transmission. Unless there was an issue with the sensor or you requested it, the old sensor would be used and just transferred over.
There is concern for parts which are hard to get to, for instance if you change out the clutch, you should change out the throw out bearing, too. Or, if you do a timing belt on a 4-cylinder engine, you'd change out the water pump as well. It just makes good sense, because the labor costs to change it out separately does not make sense considering your right there where it's at in the first place.
In your case, this sensor probably doesn't require replacement that often, so there was no concern for replacing it. It sounds like it is an unfortunate circumstance which isn't doing you very good. Like I said in the comments, though, I think I'd get a 2nd opinion about changing it out and how much it would cost you.
